# Webkit: Finding absolute position of clicked DOMElement with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, webkit

I'd like to find out the position of a clicked DOMElement in a WebView. In my delegate `-[webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:
decisionListener:]` gets called. I can extract the clicked DOM element from the dictionary passed as actionInformation parameter. But I cannot figure out how to retrieve its position.

I tried get the click location through `webview.window.currentEvent`, but that returned some an WebKit event with a bogus location.

Any ideas how to solve this without dropping down into JavaScript?

Comment: What’s bad about using Javascript in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way that should work without actual JavaScript is to use the Objective-C properties of `DOMElement`, which mirror the underlying JS properties. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be good documentation, but you can read the headers, e. g. `WebKit/Headers/DOMElement.h` etc.

Here, your best bet would be `offsetLeft/Top/Width/Height`. You need to add these to the `scrollLeft/Top` values of the document element. Also, for some elements, especially text or spans across multiple lines, calling the JS function `getBoundingClientRect()` would return better results. But you can do that from Objective-C as well, using the `WebScriptObject` API. If you need assistance with that, I can help.